# How to generate a completely void nether/end?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a skyblock world, and I am wondering how to generate the nether as a complete void with no blocks, I still want to keep the biomes and structures, just remove all blocks, I also want to do this with the end.

For the overworld it's easy to do this, you just generate a super flat world with 1 layer air, but this wouldn't work either, since I want structures, but no blocks, so if I generate a world with structures, there would be floating villages and such, but I don't want that, I only want the structures to remain, so you could build witch farms and such

As SF. said, i could use the quickcarpet skyblock mod, and it was available for 1.16

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ilmango's "Sciblock" was made like this, and he provides a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5NBQ36XkZo) for getting the pack to work in 1.14. Afterwards you should be able to upgrade your world to latest.

Comment: Yeah, but you wouldn't get those new nether biomes if you did that?